# Spotfire WebPlayer - Retrieve list of library analyses

Tags: javascript, tibco, spotfire

I'm creating a Spotfire/JavaScript mashup and I'd quite like the user to be able to select the most appropriate visualisation/analysis from a dropdown list.

However, I'd rather not hard-code the list of analyses, I'd prefer it if there was some way to programmatically poll the webplayer application and get back a list of analyses in the webplayer library.  There doesn't seem to be anything obvious in the API.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spotfire Library appears to be implemented as several tables in the Spotfire database with "LIB" prefix.

We can retrieve relevant analysis meta data from the Library with something like following query, for example:

```
SELECT LIB_ITEMS.TITLE,LIB_ITEMS.DESCRIPTION,LIB_ITEMS.CONTENT_SIZE
FROM LIB_ITEMS 
WHERE LIB_ITEMS.ITEM_TYPE = (SELECT LIB_ITEM_TYPES.TYPE_ID FROM LIB_ITEM_TYPES WHERE LIB_ITEM_TYPES.LABEL = 'dpx')
ORDER BY LIB_ITEMS.TITLE ASC
```

Hope this helps. :)